# Learning about Java MVC and Swing framework

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, frameworks

I have been looking around for tutorials on Java MVC concept and Swing framework. But, unfortunately, the ones I found aren't understandable . I want something to follow. Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: You should clarify your question by indicating whether you are interested in MVC as implemented in Swing itself (component-level), or MVC as it can be applied in an application using Swing (application-level). The 1st one is quite straightforward and has some good articles. The second one, more interesting, is more difficult to find reference about...

Comment: What articles did you find? What wasn't understandable?

Answer (score 2):

The Java Tuturials (separated into "trails") are usually a good introduction to any Java API or concept: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

As for MVC, you'll probably get the hang of that concept by checking the Swing examples and using the API properly. But this seems like a decent enough overview: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html

MVC is not a difficult concept. Focus on using the Swing classes in the appropriate manner as described in the tutorials and by reading sample code.

Comment: Are there any video tutorials about MVC and SWING class?  I tried searching on YouTube, but they are not that useful really.

Comment: Wouldn't know about those. The NetBeans site has some screencasts for using their GUI builder, in case you use that IDE: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-builder-screencast.html. However, even though a GUI builder can help you quickly get a Swing app up and running, a good understanding of the fundamentals is still very important. Videos are easy to watch, but in my experience not a substitute for going through a written tutorial and playing around with the code samples.